# Build Error in Antlr Targets

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, antlr, antlr4

Last week I went home from work and my project using Antlr 4 for C# was building normally.  I get to work this morning to resume the project and I get this build error:

Antlr4.targets(129,5): error AC1000: Unknown build error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have not made any changes to the code since I had a working build last week.  This is a problem that is effecting my entire team.  I leaning toward it being an environmental problem because I can take the same solution and copy it to a laptop that has been outside our domain since last week and it can build the project fine.  At this point I can only guess that our IT pushed something that changed out configurations but I am at a loss as to what it could be so I can fix it.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: You'll probably have the best results getting this corrected if you post it on the issue tracker for the ANTLR 4 C# target: https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/issues